# convert dataframe column from timestamp with timezone to timestamp type

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a dataframe with 3 columns. The dataframe is created from Postgres table.

How can I do a conversion from timestamptz to timestamp please?

**I did**

```
df['StartTime'] = df["StartTime"].apply(lambda x: x.tz_localize(None))
```

example of data in the StartTime :

```
2013-09-27 14:19:46.825000+02:00
2014-02-07 10:52:25.392000+01:00
```

Thank you,

Comment: Thank you ! i want to store data like this : 2013-09-27 14:19:46, 2014-02-07 10:52:25 @MrFuppes

Comment: Ah right, since you have mixed UTC offset, you'll need to apply the `lambda` as you tried. However replace tzinfo with None since mixed offset means you're dealing with datetime objects --> use `pd.to_datetime(df["StartTime"]).apply(lambda t: t.replace(tzinfo=None))`

Comment: @MrFuppes thank you i got this error **E   ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
**

Comment: ok if the Series in the df already is dtype datetime, just use `df["StartTime"].apply(lambda t: t.replace(tzinfo=None))`

Answer (score 0):

To give a more thorough answer, the point here is that in your example, you have timestamps with mixed UTC offsets. Without settings any keywords, `pandas` will convert the strings to datetime but leave the Series' type as native Python datetime, not `pandas` (numpy) datetime64. That makes it kind of hard to use built-in methods like `tz_localize`. But you can work your way around. Ex:

```
import pandas as pd
# exemplary Series
StartTime = pd.Series(["2013-09-27 14:19:46.825000+02:00", "2014-02-07 10:52:25.392000+01:00"])
# make sure we have datetime Series
StartTime = pd.to_datetime(StartTime)

# notice the dtype:
print(type(StartTime.iloc[0]))
# <class 'datetime.datetime'>

# we also cannot use dt accessor:
# print(StartTime.dt.date)
# >>> AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

# ...but we can use replace method of datetime object and remove tz info:
StartTime = StartTime.apply(lambda t: t.replace(tzinfo=None))

# now we have
StartTime
0   2013-09-27 14:19:46.825
1   2014-02-07 10:52:25.392
dtype: datetime64[ns]

# and can use e.g.
StartTime.dt.date
# 0    2013-09-27
# 1    2014-02-07
# dtype: object
```